# Trying to install express mysql in the directory but not able to do so

Tags: linux, express, ubuntu, npm

- I am trying to install express mysql in the directory.
- But I am getting the error "Sorry, name can only contain URL-friendly characters."
- I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong.
- Thanks!!!
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i will strongly advise you to read npm documentation.

- `npm init`

  > used to set up a new or existing npm package
- `npm install`

  > installs a package, and any packages that it depends on

do if you are starting a new project, try the following

```sh
npm init -y
npm install --save express mysql
```